# Performance loss using Matlab parfeval?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a relatively big file and I would like to make an interactive plot using GUIDE which plots a segment of the file and upon scrollEvent the window gets updated. (the data is appropriately replotted).

To this end a buffer of size 4 times that of the window is fetched, and when the window's center reaches 75% of the buffer, the buffer is refetched so that the window is at the center of the new buffer.

The problem with this is that when using `fread` it of course blocks until done.(which is visually disturbing)

What I tried is to create a separate `readData`  function which gets called with `f = parfeval(gcp(),@readData,1,datafile)` and on `[~,buffer]=fetchNext(f)` the `buffer` is persisted on `handles.datafile`.

**Problem:** Even though in my example (see below) `readData` only gets called once, every subsequent plotting is incredibly slow (10x the runtime of when not using `parfeval`).

**Example:**

`./test.dat` was generated by `dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.dat bs=100000 count=1024`

**This is the synchronous code to get the asynchronous one, comment out the `parfeval` and `fetchNext` function definitions shadowing the parallel ones.

```
function test()

    f = figure('Toolbar','none','Menubar','none');
    ax = axes(f);

    data = struct(  'file','./test.dat',...
                    'buffer',[],...
                    'window',[0,100000]);

    p = gcp();
    data.fileReader = parfeval(p,@readData,1,data);

    handles = struct('axes',ax,'figure',f,'data',data);

    guidata(f,handles);

    set(f,'WindowScrollWheelFcn',@scrollHandler);

end

function f = parfeval(~,fun,~,in1)
    f = struct('output',fun(in1));
end

function [id,out] = fetchNext(f,varargin)
    id = 1;
    out = f.output;
end

function buffer = readData(data)
    file = fopen(data.file,'r');
    buffer = fread(file,[128,400000],'int16');
    fclose(file);
end

function scrollHandler(hObject, eventdata, ~)
    handles = guidata(hObject);
    ax = handles.axes;
    C = get (ax, 'CurrentPoint');
    XLim = get(ax, 'XLim');
    YLim = get(ax, 'YLim');
    if XLim(1)<=C(1,1) && XLim(2)>=C(1,1) && ...
        YLim(1)<=C(1,2) && YLim(2)>=C(1,2)
        tic;
        window = handles.data.window;
        if isstruct(handles.data.fileReader) || handles.data.fileReader ~= -1
            fprintf('Reading from file\n');
            [~,handles.data.buffer] = fetchNext(handles.data.fileReader);
            handles.data.fileReader = -1;
        end
        if eventdata.VerticalScrollCount > 0 && window(2) < 399000
            window = window + 1000;
        else
            if window(1) > 1000
                window = window - 1000;
            end
        end
        handles.data.window = window;
        guidata(hObject, handles);
        plot(ax,handles.data.buffer(65,window(1)+1:window(2)));
        toc
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this using your code, but it wasn't clear to me how to interact with it correctly. It would be really helpful if you could produce a simpler standalone code-only reproduction. Also, it seems as though you're somehow suggesting that a single prior call to `parfeval` is somehow slowing down subsequent plotting?

Comment: @Edric updated the example to a code-only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed very mysterious. The problem seems to be some sort of interaction with `guidata` and the `parallel.FevalFuture` returned by `parfeval`. As a workaround, you can simply avoid overwriting that element of the struct. In other words, remove the line

```
handles.data.fileReader = -1;
```

You'll also need to check `handles.data.fileReader.Read` to make sure you don't attempt to call `fetchNext` again on an already-completed future.